# SharePoint Backup Size Question (stsadm)

Tags: sharepoint

When I backup via stsadm (Stsadm -o backup -overwrite -url %mysite% -backupmethod full -filename %file%) I get a file size of 1.5gb.  I just looked on our sql server and the database is around 18gb.  I was under the impression that using the 'full' parameter in stsadm was capturing the entire site, am I wrong?  Should I be using a 3rd-party utility to do this instead?

Comment: How are you determining the size of your SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the properties of each database to determine the size.

Turns out the log files were getting extremely large.  I shrank them following the instructions here:  [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121185921/http://geekswithblogs.net/RogueCoder/archive/2008/06/03/122588.aspx)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SF!  In the future, this kind of additional info helps the most when edited into your original question, or posted as a comment after Doug's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Stsadm will compress its backup by default - I believe using the -nofilecompression switch will give a file size closer to what you'd expect to see.